# MVC ModelState erroneously reports errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

I am receiving a model from a view.
Some of the values are automatically filled in.

However, some of the required values need to be added manually, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foobar(FooModel model, FormCollection collection)
{
    // "timePicker" is a dropdown list containing different times
    var time = collection["timePicker"].Split(':');
    model.Hours = int.Parse(time[0]);
    model.Minutes = int.Parse(time[1]);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ... // Do stuff
    }
}
```

So here's the problem:

**`ModelState.IsValid` is false.**
I debugged it, and it claims that `model.Minutes` and `model.Hours` are not assigned to.
...Which isn't true, because I had *just assigned* them values!

I considered using `ModelState.Clear()`, but I don't want to need to manually check whether all the rest of the information is valid.

Is there any other way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the model binding, putting errors in `ModelState`, has been done before entering your action.

So the `Minutes` and `Hours` errors are in the ModelState before you add values in Hours and Minutes (which makes it invalid).

You might just remove these errors (and not all errors, as `Clear()` does) , by doing :

```
ModelState.Remove("Hours");
ModelState.Remove("Minutes");
```

Another way to resolve this would be to create (and use) a custom ModelBinder.

Comment: +1, but I can't remember whether an exception is thrown if the key doesn't exist. Probably doesn't :)

Comment: @mattytommo well, in this case, the key should always exist. By the way, the method just returns false if the key can't be removed (readonly dictionary or non existing key), and true if key has been removed.

Comment: @JacobSpire by the way, you could also use a ViewModel int this case, it would be probably nicer (or, as said, a custom ModelBinder).

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus You would still need to remove the invalid model state within a custom modelbinder though right?